# What is the roll of CPU cores in determining JVM heap sizes?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Recently I read an article stating that 2 -4 GB of heap per four core must be allocated on a site. I do understand that faster CPU and more cores means more throughput from single VM, perhaps faster GC execution but what is the exact relationship. I am looking for some details like benchmarks etc.

Comment: I am unable to get back the link

Comment: It was on websphere process server

Answer (score 1):

Larger the Heap size is, the longer GC pause times will be. The shorter it is, the more expensive GC will be (usually). A good guideline is 100 MB per CPU core.